# How to restore the state of a angular dart program based on the url?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In an Angular.Dart application, different views can be managed via routes.

How do I read the current route **(in a piece of code not related to a view)**, such as to update the application state if someone copy/pastes an url ? (i.e. the entry point of the application is not the original, default, url)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO his is the default behaviour.

see
https://angulardart.org/tutorial/08-ch06-view.html 'Connecting a route to a view'

You can encode parameters in the url and initialize your components using this values (state), 
no matter if you open the URL using a link in your application or enter it manually.

Comment: My question was related to the state of other parts of the application, other than just the view.

Comment: You should edit your question to make that clear, probably with a use case example.